# How to index file names on a disk with Java

Tags: java, file, elasticsearch, search

I write a service which stores millions files (20-30mb file) on a disk and I need to write a search function to find a file by name (there is no need to search file content) or view files in explorer (for example, navigate in browser as a folder structure). I want to make it fast, reliable and simple in Java. Say, I plan to run two services both of which can be used to upload a file or search files by name pattern. What will be the best technology/approach to use to implement this? Store a file on a disk as well as the path and name in the database, search against the database and fetch findings by path from the database? Any other good ideas? I thought about elasticsearch but looks like a heavy solution.

Comment: Elasticsearch is built on Lucene. You could try that. Otherwise, just a simple SQL database would work with the `LIKE` query

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad and rather not in a format of SO (concrete programming questions mostly with code snippets that try to address a concrete technical difficulty given the set of technologies).

There are many ways to fulfill your requirements. Yet, based solely on the information presented in your question, its impossible to recommend something because we don't really know your requirements. I'll explain:

> I plan to run two services both of which can be used to upload a file or search files by name pattern.

Does this mean that the file system has to be distributed?
If so, consider Cloud solutions style aws's S3.

If you can't run in the cloud, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems) you can find a comprehensive list of distributed filesystems.

Elasticsearch can also work of course as a search engine, but its more a full fledged search engine, so looks like an overkill for me in this case.

You might want to work directly with lucene so that you won't need to run an additional process that also might fail (ES is built on top of lucene). Lucene will store its index directly on the filesystem, again if it meets the requirements.

Now you're talking also about the database - again a possible direction especially if you're already have one in your project. In general relational database management servers have some support of searching but there are more advanced solutions: in PostgreSQL for example you have a GIN index (inverted index) again the same concepts for full text search that go way beyond standard's SQL's `LIKE` Operator.

Yet another idea: go with a local disk. If you're on linux there is an indexing utility called "locate" that you can delegate the index creation to.

So the choice is yours.